# Android WebView, not responding to change

Tags: java, android, web

I have a simple android application, an activity with a WebView as follows:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gfx);
        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.somepage.com");

    }
```

My internet page is being changed by some ajax actions, first it shows a progress bar then it redirects to another page.
What happens to me that my browser stays in the first page, and doesn't respond to the changes in the page, it doesn't act like a real browser.
If I open the page directly in the browser using:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.somepage.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

it works fine.